# Print Matching line and one line before from the matched line

Tags: python, linux, awk, sed, grep

looking forward to print Matching line in a file on Linux host and one line before from the matched line included into one line.

Below is just the content from the log file:

```
[2020/02/18 08:25:21.229198,  1] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1206(get_cached_ldap_connect)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 1 try!
[2020/02/18 08:25:21.229221,  2] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:287(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Problem during LDAPsearch: Timed out
```

**What i have tried:**

I have tried following with `grep` and `sed` which somehow works..

```
$ egrep -B 1 "failed|Timed" /var/log/samba/smbd.log.old |tr -d "\n" | sed "s/--/\n/g"


[2020/02/18 08:25:21.229198,  1] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1206(get_cached_ldap_connect)  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 1 try!
[2020/02/18 08:25:21.229221,  2] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:287(smbldap_search_domain_info) smbldap_search_domain_info: Problem during LDAPsearch: Timed out
```

This does not looks to be a cleaner solution, i'm looking forward some expert one lines, one liner is acceptable with awk, sed, grep or even python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with `awk` alone:

```
awk ' /Timed|failed/ { print previous, $0; }; {previous = $0;}' /var/log/samba/smbd.log.old
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'N;/\n.*\(failed\|Timed\)/s/\n//p;D' file
```

Turn off implicit printing. Append the next line. If the appended line contains `failed` or `Timed`, delete the newline and print the result. Delete the first line in the pattern space and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following `tac` + `awk` solution:

```
tac Input_file | awk '/failed/{found=1;val=$0;next} found && NF{print $0,val;val=found=""}'
```

OR adding a non-one liner form of solution:

```
tac Input_file | 
awk '
  /failed/{
    found=1
    val=$0
    next
  }
  found && NF{
    print $0,val
    val=found=""
  }
'
```